# Using Matlab to obtain data from a graph

Tags: matlab

I currently have a large number of 1D graphs that i would like to use to calculate a value. I would like the code to take the y values at 20 and 100 on the X axis, and then do the log10 of the x value at 20 divided by the x value at 100.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code that you can modify for your problem:

```
% Data
X = (1:100)';
Y = X*5 + 10;

% Calculation
result = log10(X(Y == 20)) / X(Y == 100);
```

The expression `Y == 20` returns a logical array of the indices of `Y` for which this is true. Putting this in `X` gives the X values at those indices. In the case of the simple function plotted here, there is exactly one such point so we get a scalar value. For more complex value searching inside arrays you should use the [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function.